# pandas is (mis)reading "1" as NaN in csv file

Tags: python, pandas, csv, nan

I am using pandas to read a csv file, but bizarrely it's not recognising number "1". Instead, it displays them as NaNs. Any ideas on why and how to fix them?

When I open the csv file in Sublime (or text editor), those NaNs are actually 1's.

This es a csv file example (look at bottom right):

```
326066,NULL,"2011-11-13",2
326210,NULL,"2011-11-14",4
326218,NULL,"2011-11-10",118
326222,NULL,"2011-11-11",150
326607,NULL,"2011-11-10",1
327243,NULL,"2011-11-14",1
```

And this is what pandas reads:

```
0   326066  NaN 2011-11-13  2.0
1   326210  NaN 2011-11-14  4.0
2   326218  NaN 2011-11-10  118.0
3   326222  NaN 2011-11-11  150.0
4   326607  NaN 2011-11-10  NaN
5   327243  NaN 2011-11-14  NaN
```

Help!

I tried making my own file, and same problem. Also tried reading that columns as .astype(int) but no success :\

Comment: I can't reproduce it, I have the `1`s, as expected. Are you sure you don't have hidden special characters?

Comment: Invisible characters? Check in a hex editor

Comment: A zero-width character could be there for some reason. Some editors have ["gremlins" mode](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=nhoizey.gremlins) which point these out.

Comment: Hello, is the example a direct copy_paste, or a construct for the question? I wonder if such hidden characters would appear on our side, this way or another